# Async and await nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

```
async function getInfoByName(name) {
    return await search.getInfo(name);
}

console.log(getInfoByName('title'));
```

It returns `Promise { <Pending> }`, how can I return the value that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
getInfoByName('title').then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

It basically impossible to return value from asynchronus call inside synchronus function. You can pass callback to your asynchronus and call it in `then` section. Please see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for more explanation and examples

Comment: I did a console log and it works but how to return this value from function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the promise [then callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

```
getInfoByName('title').then((result) => { 
  console.log(result))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your function 'getInfo' you should 'resolve' the value you want to return. You can do this in the promise which is in the 'getInfo' function.

Comment: I did it

return new Promise(resolve => {resolve("True")}

for an example